# Why does assigning a value to a string in a struct crash the program?

Tags: c++, string, struct

I have commented out the problematic string, attempted to pass the input to a string that is not a member of the struct, then passing it to the correct string, to no avail. To achieve the intended function, the string must go through this struct. Where is it going wrong?
Structure code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class passingdata
{
    public:
    passingdata()
    {
        //constructor
    };
    ~passingdata()
    {
        //destructor
    };
    int convertedResponse;
    const string headers[4] = {"Labor/Materials", "Cost (per unit)", "Total Units", "Total Cost"}; //this is all to be written to a file later.
    struct dynInputs
    {
        string name;
        int perCost;
        int unitTotal;
        int totalCost = perCost * unitTotal;
    };
    void acceptInputs()
    {
        string name = "";
        string response = "";
        const string positiveResponse = "yes";
        cout << "Would you like to insert a label?" << endl;
        getline(cin, response);
        if (response == positiveResponse)
        {
            populateSaveData();
        }
        else
        {
            //nothing yet
        }
    }

    void populateSaveData()
    {
        if (convertedResponse = 1)
        {
            cout << "How many labels would you like to create?" << endl;

            int labelCount;
            cin >> labelCount;
            cin.clear();
            int labelsNeeded = labelCount;
            dynInputs* dynamicInputs;
            dynamicInputs = new dynInputs[labelsNeeded];
            while (labelsNeeded > 0)
            {
                cout << "please type the name for this row" << endl;
                cin.ignore();
                //string tempName = "";
                //getline(cin, tempName); this works!
                getline(cin, dynamicInputs[labelsNeeded].name); //this breaks, goes to trash memory when done this way
                system("pause");
                cin.clear();
                //tempName = dynamicInputs[labelsNeeded].name; breaks as well
                cout << dynamicInputs[labelsNeeded].name << endl;
                //cout << tempName << endl;
                system("pause");
                cout << "please type the cost of the unit, and the number of units" << endl;
                cin >> dynamicInputs[labelsNeeded].perCost;
                cin.clear();
                cin >> dynamicInputs[labelsNeeded].unitTotal;
                cin.clear();
                labelsNeeded--;
            }
            cout << dynamicInputs[0].unitTotal << endl;
```

The `dynamicInputs[labelsNeeded]` array points to junk memory, yet I'm unsure of why it only crashes assigning value to the string.

Comment: This code example is incomplete. You have not shown the definition of `dynamicInputs`, but I'm willing to bet it's an array or similar and you are writing past the end of it.

Comment: I thought I had grabbed it, my mistake. it has been updated. I don't understand how I would be writing past the end of it, as the integer labelsNeeded never changes, and it doesn't reach the string definition without crashing.  It accepts the integer values, just not the string.

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve]. Guessing `labelsNeeded` goes out of valid range.

Comment: Why use new?  dynamicInputs = new dynInputs[labelCount];  specially when labelCount is a runtime variable you should std::vector.

Also   `int totalCost = perCost * unitTotal;` will not magically update when you change `perCost` or `unitTotal` now it is calculated once from unitialized variables.

Comment: Have you initialize labelsNeeded to 0?

Comment: What is the value of `labelCount`? What is the value of `labelsNeeded`? You're not showing these either. These are questions you should be asking yourself. As part of debugging an issue, you must verify all assumptions you are making about your program and its state.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I don't understand why initializing ```lablesNeeded``` or any other variables to 0 would have to do with the string if the rest of the structure is assigned values without issue.  I used new as it was how I was shown in the example I followed (from here I believe), and I've not at all used std::vector.

Comment: @paddy I made a wildly incorrect assumption that i included all necessary information in my comments.  labelCount is a runtime variable that passes the value to labelsNeeded, which is used to drive the while loop.

Comment: Because assigning to a `string` first destroys whatever string was there. If you happen to assign to garbage memory, that is interpreted as a `string` instance and it tries to free a garbage pointer. This is a common reason for a crash. This should show up plain as day if you run your code under a debugger and check the address that `dynamicInputs[labelsNeeded]` resolves to. Or just check that the value of `labelsNeeded <= labelCount`. Writing `unitTotal` and `perCost` "only" trashes memory without necessarily crashing.

Comment: @Botje that makes sense, as passing any value to the string contained in my structure crashes it. Passing value (or receiving input for) tempName works perfectly fine.  I've found the garbage memory that it's attempting to write to, although I'm unsure of how to fix the issue.

Comment: There are three options: either your array index was out of bounds (ie `labelsNeeded` exceeds the size of the allocated array, you allocated memory with malloc instead of new (which does not know about constructors), or something else trashed the memory behind your back. Again, use a debugger and just *look*.

Comment: @Botje I'm looking at the debugger, and it's showing the struct as trying to reference a string array created far earlier in the runtime, and i dont understand the *why it's doing that, because I've never worked with structures with strings and integers at the same time.* I don't understand how labelsNeeded could exceed the size when the *rest of the code* works perfectly fine when I comment out the string.  I have never used malloc, so *I have no clue what trashed the memory, or how to figure it out.* I'm not trying to be hostile, but I've no clue how to fully use the tools you are advising.

Comment: We are having to take educated guesses about the issue, because you haven't really provided solid information about the program. We have snippets of it, you haven't told us the values of some really important variables, and you are asserting that you think these things don't matter. They do. If you are unsure about how to provide enough detail, post the entire program and show the input/output.

Comment: @paddy thank you. I will update the code momentarily, complete with the commented out code to show what I have attempted.

Comment: You create an array of size `labelsNeeded` and then write to elements at index `labelsNeeded` which is one past the last valid index. That invokes *undefined behavior*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `labelsNeeded` you store the size of the array.

Then in the first iteration you use `labelsNeeded` to index into your array. Since C++ indexes an array starting from 0, the largest possible valid index is (the size of the array) - 1.

Eg.: For an array of size 4, your valid index range is [0, 1, 2, 3].

Now what you are doing is setting `labelsNeeded` to equal `labelCount` and then allocate an array of the size equalig `labelsNeeded`. And then in the first iteration you use the value of `labelsNeeded` as an index with this original value for accessing an element in your array. Which goes past the valid range of your array. Hence the program crashes.

I see that at the and of the iteration you decrement `labelsNeeded` but that is too late considering that you already tried to use the original value earlier in the code.

Your `labelsNeeded > 0` condition for your while loop is also incorrect if you are using this "decrement the index at the end of the iteration" solution since it will fail to write the first (at index 0) element of your array.

Try moving the `labelsNeeded--` line to the beginning of the iteration.

Note:

As to "why it only crashes assigning value to the string".

C++ (or rather the runtime) does not care whether your pointer points to a valid address or not. Simply because a pointer is just a memory address. By it self it is just a number stored in memory. A pointer that references invalid memory will only crash your program (or do other weird stuff) if you want to dereference it or in other words -> If you want to actually use the pointer to *access* that place in memory. It is not the "invalid" memory address in the pointer that crashes but the act of trying to access the memory at that address. The distinction may look subtle but is very important nonetheless. You can have any number of "null pointers" in the program as long as you don't try to dereference null.

Note 2:

Yours is an especially interesting mode of failure since it can fail in one of two places:

1. Since you are indexing an element that is one past the end of the array, that may as well coincide with the end of the heap that was assigned to the program. So it may crash there. But... Most likely your array is not allocated in such a place and there will still be accessible heap past the end of your array so dereferencing one element past your array may as well give you "something" and by something I mean some memory content cast to the type that you have. But of course from your point of view that is some random data.
2. If execution survived the previous section and now you have a struct with random data, you also have your string in your struct that is also filled with random garbage. Which means its pointer to the actual string content is also random (most likely pointing somewhere before or past your addressable space) as well as its size and other state information also being garbage. So if you reassign that string then its original content pointer will likely be accessed (eg.: deallocation) which will result in a crash.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand what happened:
1. Had I made the array size of labelCount, then decrementing ```labelsNeeded``` to control the slot of the array (ie the first entry is assigned to 0), it sounds like it would prevent accessing data outside of the array.
2. Essentially what's happening is I can't pass values to the array, because in the memory the array isn't where the code is trying to write to. 
So a solution for #1 would be to change the array's size to labelCount, as stated, and a solution to #2 would be figuring out where the array goes in heap, OR rewriting the code.

Comment: Your problem is that you are using the index "labelsNeeded" incorrectly.
You want to iterate through the array from last to first. So your index should start at the last element. Then decrement it each iteration until you get to the first element.
But in your code, your index starts at one past the last element of the array (!!!). So if theoretically your array size is 4. Then the labelsNeeded should have the value 3 at the first iteration (since the last valid array index is (size - 1)). But you have 4. So the first iteration indexes one past the end of the array. Which leads to trouble.

Comment: Now. If you want to fix this. You can either

1. Change the code to start from the correct index:

...

dynInputs* dynamicInputs;

dynamicInputs = new dynInputs[labelCount];

int labelsNeeded = labelCount - 1;

while (labelsNeeded >= 0) {

...

Note that the condition of the while loop also has a subtle change which is needed because otherwise your iteration will stop after the index value of 1. Which means it would skip index 0. Which is incorrect.

Comment: Alternatively
2. 
You can move the line
labelsNeeded--;
To the beginning of the while loop like so without changing anything else:
...
while (labelsNeeded > 0)
{
    labelsNeeded--;
    cout << "please type the name for this row" << endl;
...
Now you "pre-decrement" labelsNeeded to the correct value (from 4 to 3 in our theoretical example) before actually trying to access anything with it. And the added bonus is that labelsNeeded is still greater than 0 in the last iteration, but it will be decremented to 0 before being used, so your original condition for the while will be correct.